# how to create a script for checking if ssh is running and if not restart it

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I'm running a headless system with a raspberry pi and after a while of not connecting via ssh the system will stop responding to ssh, it is not the Wi-Fi dongle falling asleep, I have checked, seeing I have a piglow running piglow-sysmon, and the part of the pi glow that monitors network activity does show activity when the pi stops responding to ssh. I found a nice script for checking if Wi-Fi is up and if not restart it, although im not that great with bash scripting, and cannot figure out how or if i can mod it to work with ssh instead of Wi-Fi, if anyone can help me mod it, or provide a small quick one, I'm using cron to run it (once I can get it modded) every few minutes

here the script I'm trying to mod

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/home/pi/network-monitor.log

if ifconfig wlan0 | grep -q "inet addr:" ;
then
        echo "$(date "+%m %d %Y %T") : Wifi OK" >> $LOGFILE
else
        echo "$(date "+%m %d %Y %T") : Wifi connection down! Attempting reconnection." >> $LOGFILE
        ifup --force wlan0
        OUT=$? #save exit status of last command to decide what to do next
        if [ $OUT -eq 0 ] ; then
                STATE=$(ifconfig wlan0 | grep "inet addr:")
                echo "$(date "+%m %d %Y %T") : Network connection reset. Current state is" $STATE >> $LOGFILE
        else
                echo "$(date "+%m %d %Y %T") : Failed to reset wifi connection" >> $LOGFILE
        fi
fi
```

Comment: the ssh daemon should always be running you don't need a script to monitor/restart it, except someone or something is shutting it down in the background, to your question `/etc/init.d/sshd start` in your cron job should do the trick though I doubt that's your problem

Comment: IIRC restarting sshd will not sever an existing ssh connection, so you could run the sshd restart script every few minutes via cron. That's pretty lazy, but it would be enough, depending on what you need. If not, you can find out if sshd is running with `ps -elf|grep 'usr/sbin/sshd'|grep -v grep`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script. It makes a few assumptions:

1) Your account has its own ssh key in the `authorized_keys` file, so that "ssh localhost" essentially just gives you another shell, without prompting for a password

2) If the ssh command does not complete in three seconds, it would be safe to assume that the ssh daemon is up, but stuck for some reason:

```
#! /bin/bash

ssh localhost /bin/true &

sleep 3; kill -9 $!

if wait $!
then
    echo Up
else
    echo Down
fi
```

A bit crude, but should be effective. It's up to you to figure out how to restart the ssh service in an optimum way, here. Fill in the blanks.

You may also want to discard all standard error here, as it'll likely to have some unimportant noise...

If, on the other hand, this script reports that the ssh service is running, but you still can't connect from the outside, the problem is not the ssh service, but it lies elsewhere, so it's back to the drawing board for you.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still confused where are the blanks? and where should i put this script? sorry I'm new to bash

Comment: The only one who knows the answer to the question is you. Different Linux distributions offer different ways of restarting services, and scheduling jobs. Only you know which Linux distribution you're running on your system, so only you know the answer to this question. If you don't, perhaps you're going too fast, and this project is too much for you. Before you should be trying to run your own raspberri pi server, perhaps you want to take a time out, and study Linux, and Linux distributions, in general. How they work, and how to administer them.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I did tag Rasbian in my post, and I'm not going too fast i have made multiple arch linux installations, i just need to find a way to keep the pi's ssh alive, and im more familiar with c++, and bash programming just looks like gibberish to me, i would like to mod it, ill just put it as a start up, but should i just replace echo up with services ssh restart?

Comment: Although I could just give the answer, I'll be doing you a disservice, because you won't learn anything from this. Instead, I'll tell you how you should've been able to figure out the answer yourself even if you didn't know much about bash -- and you'll actually learn something new. Sorry, but not knowing bash isn't an excuse for not doing a simple experiment: running this script when ssh is up, and see what it does; then running this script again when ssh is down, and see what it does. If you did that, it should've been obvious to you how exactly this script should be modified.